# Accessing "temporary_file_path()" on a file smaller than 2.5 megabytes in Django

Tags: python, django, file, storage

I am successfully able to access the temporary_file_path() on files larger than 2.5 megabytes.  In the Django docs it says that files smaller than 2.5 megabytes are not stored temporarily so you cannot use this method.  I was wondering how to change the default behavior of Django so that it temporarily stores all files regardless of size.

Comment: I assume it has to do with changing the default FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE but I don't know where to change that.  In the settings or in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Alright.  I actually figured this out pretty much right away after asking the question.

If you just add

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 0
```

in settings.py it changes the file size needed for you to access a temporary path.